# PHP: Cookies Location, Availability

Tags: php, cookies

I've heard that cookies are small txt files. right?

when I use command **setcookie()** in index.php, where does it get stored? In hard drive.

Which files have access to cookies? for example:

I use **setcookie()** in **index.php** and **print_r($_COOKIE)** in **secondpage.php** and it prints fine (in same folder). but another page from outside can't. Are Cookies bound to files?

Sorry for silly question but there are many other cookies form other websites. how does my browser know which set cookies to send via HTTP Request?

What concept am i missing?

tnx

Comment: a cookie is linked to a path and domain, take a look at the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `setcookie` withouut parameters default are used. Normally cookie is used only for the same domain and the current path.

So each time you visit website, this website may use only cookies that were set to this domain and not for other domains.

You have to be aware that if you are at

`http://yourdomain.com/directory/` url

by default PHP will set cookie for `/directory/` directory what mean that you won't be able to read this cookie when you are at `http://yourdomain.com` directory. So if you have in your domain directory-like structure you need to always set `/` as path when you set cookie

You can look at [setcookie documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) to read more.

Comment: Probably it depends on browser implementation. For example Firefox stores them in sqlite database and not as txt files so all your cookies you have inside one SQLite file